# How to send the Asynchronous http api get with params having nested braces?

Tags: android, http, elasticsearch, get

I am using the Android Asynchronous Http Client api get, post and put to get, post and put information to my elastic search storage. I am stuck at a point where I need to search for a user's email in my Elastic search storage index and parse the result received in the json object. The corresponding curl command looks like below

```
curl -XGET "http://<ess server ip>:9200/test_user_type/_doc/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"query" : { "bool": { "must":{ "match" : {                       "email" : "123@xyz.com" } } } }}'
```

But I am getting a clue how to pass on the parameters with braces to the get api

```
{"query" : { "bool": { "must":{ "match" : {"email" : "123@xyz.com" } } } }}
```

I have tried below method to prepare a string with all those nested braces and variable values but the get api expected the params to be passed and not the string.

```
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setBasicAuth("username","password");
        client.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        StringBuilder bulk = new StringBuilder();

        bulk.append("{ \"query\" :{ \"bool\" : { \"must\" :{ \"match\" :{ \"email\" : \"123@xyz.com\"");
        bulk.toString();
        
        client.get("http://localhost:9200/test_user_type/_doc/_search", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                    }
                }
        );
```

So, I want to know how can I pass bulk.toString() in the get api so that the curl gets formed in the format as posted above or if there is any other method I can do that.

Note: I am using Android Asynchronous HTTP client api because on googling I got the impression that Elasticsearch storage api in the Android studio do not completely works.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A querystring should be url encoded.

Comment: `http://localhost:9200/` ? Where is your server running?

Comment: The url I pasted as an example but my Elastic search storage is running on an external server (91.240.216.182) so the URL I am using is http://91.240.216.182:9200